# redis use in rails, how many use two?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

So lots of people use redis (often via sidekiq) for their ActiveJob queues.

And redis is also a pretty good candidate for use as an [ActiveSupport::Cache](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html) backend.

But it seems to me you'd want somewhat different redis configuration for these two cases. For the Cache use, you would likely want to [configure redis as an LRU cache](https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache), automatically evicting less recently used entries when it gets to a certain size boundary.

But for the ActiveJob queue use, you of course don't want it dropping queued jobs  in an LRU fashion, it's important redis never 'expires' anything on it's own.

I don't *think* there's a way to use the same redis instance in both of these ways simultaneously.

So... is it common to actually use *two* redis instances with your Rails? Or is there another way around this I'm missing? Or is redis not actually popular for ActiveSupport::Cache backend, are people using something else?

Comment: I don't think it's common to use the same redis instance for both cases. You should configure redis in a different manner for those separate cases.
https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache
mperham gives a few tuning advices on his wiki page for redis with sidekiq: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis#tuning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is common to use multiple differently-configured Redis instances.

Sidekiq [explicitly documents that](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis#multiple-redis-instances) as the recommended configuration:

> Many people use Redis as a cache [..] but it's important that Sidekiq be run against a Redis instance that is not configured as a cache but as a persistent store. I recommend using two separate Redis instances, each configured appropriately, if you wish to use Redis for caching and Sidekiq.